# SumIF values <> "#NV" in the next column

Tags: excel, vba, formula

my excelsheets look like this:
[image]

Then I tried it with the formula:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B200;B1:B200<>"#NV";B:B)
```

But it seems wrong. I want to summarize all numbers if is not #NV in each section (11111, 22222). Each numbers 2,3,4,6,9 belongs to the group 11111. I want to determine the sum of all the values which is allocated to the group **11111**.

For 11111: Sums over the cell B2:B6, for 22222, sums over B8:B12. That is what I want to do.

Hope you can help me. If it is possible to have a macro, I would be very thankful, if you can share with your ideas.
Thanks

Comment: try `;"<>#NV";` instead of `;B1:B200<>"#NV";`

Comment: thanks, I need it for each sections, means for 11111, it should only counts B2:B6, for 2222, it should only counts B8:B12

Comment: Is "#NV" the German equivalent for "#NA"? If you select a cell returning this 'string' and put in VBA the next code line `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value`, what does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: In other words, is it a formula error or a string?

Comment: @FaneDuru, yeah "#NV" is equivalent to "#NA".  And it is a formula error, means no value was found. Because I use VLOOKUP to find the values.

Comment: Did you try tde code line I suggested?

Comment: Isn't it possible to have two such consecutive "#NV" errors?

Comment: Still alive? You received two answers... Couldn't you find some time to check them and send some feedback...?

Answer (score 0):

### INDIRECT ft. ARRAY FORMULA

[image]

- It is highly advised that you replace the occurrences of `$B:$B` with the actual ranges e.g. `$B$1:$B$100`
- The following two formulas are to be copied to `C1` and `D1`. The second is an array formula and you have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> if you don't have `365`.
- It's a terrible solution, because the first formula uses indirect which is a volatile (updating after every calculation) function and the second is an array formula. The second should be put in the first instead of `D1` but it doesn't work (I'm using Excel 2019). So you have to use an extra column for it. Maybe 365 could accept it.
- Hopefully someone will use this information to create a more efficient solution.

**The Formulas**

These two are the ones you need in `C1` and `D1`:

```
=IF($B2<>"#NV","",SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(D1,2,4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),2,4))))
=IF($B2<>"#NV","",SMALL(IF($B:$B="#NV",ROW($B:$B)-ROW(INDEX($B:$B,1,1))+2),COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,"#NV")))
```

This one counts the number of occurrences of "#NV" from `B$1` to the current row.

```
=COUNTIF(B$1:B6,"#NV")
```

This one is an array formula and returns the row after the first occurrence of "#NV". Note the `+2` instead of `+1` is for the row below, and the `1` after it represents the first occurrence.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($B:$B="#NV",ROW($B:$B)-ROW(INDEX($B:$B,1,1))+2),1),"")
```

Similarly to the previous, this one is an array formula and returns the row after the last occurrence of "#NV".

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($B:$B="#NV",ROW($B:$B)-ROW(INDEX($B:$B,1,1))+2),COUNTIF(B$1:B6,"#NV")),"")
```

This is the `SUM`/`INDIRECT` formula: Note the first number `2` is the number to be replaced by the array formula, and the `6` is to be replaced by the last `ROW` formula.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,2,4)&":"&ADDRESS(6,2,4)))
```

The `ROW` formula.

```
=ROW()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next VBA code, please. It creates a range from the error cells of B:B filled column range and exploit the discontinuous range `Areas` addresses. You did not answer my question regarding the possibility to have two consecutive such errors. Anyhow, the following code is able to deal with such situations, too. If no possible consecutive error rows, the code can be simplified:

```
Sub testErrorRng()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngErr As Range, lastRow As Long, Ar As Range
 Dim startSum As String, endSum As String, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rngErr = sh.Range("B1:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
 
 For Each Ar In rngErr.Areas
    i = i + 1
    If i = 1 Then
        If Ar.cells.count = 1 Then
            If Ar.Address = "$B$1" Then
                startSum = Ar.Offset(1).Address
            Else
                Ar.Offset(-1, 1).Formula = "=Sum(B1:" & Ar.Offset(-1).Address & ")"
                startSum = Ar.Offset(1).Address
            End If
        Else
            startSum = Ar.cells(Ar.cells.count + 1).Address
        End If
    Else
            If Ar.cells.count = 1 Then
                endSum = Ar.Offset(-1).Address
                Ar.Offset(-1, 1).Formula = "=Sum(" & startSum & ":" & endSum & ")"
                startSum = Ar.Offset(1).Address
                
            Else
                endSum = Ar.cells(1).Offset(-1).Address
                 Ar.cells(1).Offset(-1, 1).Formula = "=Sum(" & startSum & ":" & endSum & ")"
                startSum = Ar.cells(Ar.cells.count + 1).Address                
            End If
    End If
 Next
 If rngErr.Areas(rngErr.Areas.count).row < lastRow Then
    endSum = sh.Range("B" & lastRow).Address
    sh.Range("C" & lastRow).Formula = "=Sum(" & startSum & ":" & endSum & ")"
 End If
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Edited**:

Shorter version for no consecutive error rows:

```
Sub testErrorRngSimple()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngErr As Range, lastRow As Long, Ar As Range
 Dim startSum As String, endSum As String, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rngErr = sh.Range("B1:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
 
 For Each Ar In rngErr.Areas
    i = i + 1
    If i = 1 Then
        If Ar.Address = "$B$1" Then
            startSum = Ar.Offset(1).Address
        Else
            Ar.Offset(-1, 1).Formula = "=Sum(B1:" & Ar.Offset(-1).Address & ")"
            startSum = Ar.Offset(1).Address
        End If
    Else
        endSum = Ar.Offset(-1).Address
        Ar.Offset(-1, 1).Formula = "=Sum(" & startSum & ":" & endSum & ")"
        startSum = Ar.Offset(1).Address
    End If
 Next
 If rngErr.Areas(rngErr.Areas.count).row < lastRow Then
    endSum = sh.Range("B" & lastRow).Address
    sh.Range("C" & lastRow).Formula = "=Sum(" & startSum & ":" & endSum & ")"
 End If
End Sub
```